# Shared memory : Let's talk about its specificity

Tags: c++, shared-memory, heap-memory

Let's consider the following pseudo-code between two processes **P1** and **P2**:
**In process P1:**

```
struct SharedStruct
{
    int i;
    void *pData;
};

HANDLE hMapFile = CreateFileMapping("Global\\MyFileMappingObject")  
LPCTSTR pBuf = (LPTSTR) MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, ...) 

SharedStruct mySharedStruct;
mySharedStruct.i=33;

mySharedStruct.pData = (void*) calloc (1, 10);

memcpy ( (void*) pBuf, (void*) (&mySharedStruct), sizeof (mySharedStruct));
```

**In process P2:**

```
hMapFile hMapFile = OpenFileMapping("Global\\MyFileMappingObject")  
SharedStruct *pSharedStruct_P2 = (SharedStruct *) MapViewOfFile (hMapFile,...)
...
```

**The problem:**
**pSharedStruct_P2->pData** is a **local P1 memory adress** which cannot be used by **P2**

**Reflection:**
is the use of shared memories limited only to basic types (int, float, ...)? or there is another use of shared memories to support sharing of local addresses ?

Answer (score 0):

You can store references to other objects using offsets instead of regular pointers. For example, instead of this:

```
struct Foo {
    double a;
    double b;
    double* a_or_b;
};

Foo x{1, 2, nullptr};
x.a_or_b = &a;
```

You can do this:

```
struct Foo {
    double  a;
    double  b;
    ptrdiff_t a_or_b;
};

Foo x{1, 2, 0};
x.a_or_b = static_cast<const char*>(&a) - static_cast<const char*>(&a_or_b);
```

As you can see, it's quite a bit more fiddly than using regular pointers! The offset variable and the original variable don't need to be in the same struct like this by the way, that's just to make the example simpler... they just need to be in the same block of mapped memory.

There are [containers in boost.interprocess](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/interprocess/allocators_containers.html#interprocess.allocators_containers.containers_explained.containers), along the lines of std::string and std::map, that work this internally. They exist precisely so that you can use them in this sort of situation. That library has lots of other useful facilities for manipulating shared memory that you may wish to use anyway, such as platform-independent APIs for mapping the shared memory and interprocess mutexes.

Other libraries that have this sort of offset form are [FlatBuffers](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/) and [Cap'n Proto](https://capnproto.org/). In those cases, the motivation for using offsets internally is slightly different (it's so that the serialisation to disk or on the network is exactly the same as the in-memory representation), but it still would work fine for shared memory.

Comment: Care with pointer arithmetic though, `static_cast<const char*>(x.a) - static_cast<const char*>(x.a_or_b)` is pedantically UB if I  am correct.

Comment: @Arthur Tacca thank you for your comment but I don't see how that could solve my problem of sharing locally reserved data on the heap of a process using functions like: malloc, calloc, ...
Suppose that the instruction `mySharedStruct.pData = (void*) calloc (1, 10);` returns the address **0x000e7c80** which symbolizes a void * (or more complicated a : `void **`) in P1 Heap.
How to make the address **0x000e7c80** usable by P2 ?! because this address is not part of its heap and any access attempt will generate a memory access violation

Comment: @Jarod42 I think you should be alright so long as both objects are in a memory-mapped file, because they both originate from a single array of `char`. (Also your comment made me realise I missed a couple of `&`, now fixed.)

Comment: @Landstalker You will certainly need to allocate those pointed-to objects within the memory-mapped file, either by coping them from elsewhere or by allocating them there in the first place.

Comment: @ArthurTacca I agree. It is therefore necessary to add an **additional explicit management**

Comment: With [pointer arithmetic](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Additive_operators), I think you need `static_cast<std::ptrdiff_t>(&a) - static_cast<std::ptrdiff_t>(&a_or_b)` to avoid UB. and similar care for the other way... `enum class AOrB{A, B};` seems simpler.

Comment: @Jarod42 Seems like my code is covered by the third bullet point of 2 from that link: "both are pointers to the same completely-defined object types, ignoring cv-qualifiers. In this case, the result type is std::ptrdiff_t". An enum would work in this toy example but it is meant to illustrate a more general situation where you can have arbitrarily many variables scattered around and not all within the same struct, so an enum would not work there.